# Why in Symfony2 is $form->isValid() returning true, when one of its constraints returns false?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a simple class constraint validator which is referenced correctly in my entity and I can see that it is being called and returning **false** when I validate my form based on the entity, but `$form->isValid()` is returning **true**.

Any idea why this is happening? Surely any constraint returning false should cause the form to be invalid?

Entity:

```
* @ACMEAssert\ExampleConstraint()
```

ACMEConstraint:

```
**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ExampleConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'acme.example.validator.example';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return Constraint::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

ACMEValidator:

```
class ExampleValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function isValid($entity, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Set an error message (Violation):

```
$this->context->addViolation('bar', array(), null);
```

Comment: Yep ta, as shown here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator